# How do i delete a file? And file questions about limits? Java Android

Tags: java, android

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(string.getBytes()
fos.close();
```

Above is how i write my files. Now is there a limit to it? i'm asking this because i set some text to it that i get from my text view, then later, when i get the text from that file, it isn't the full text.Secondly, how would i delete a file when using the above method?

Answer (score 0):

Well for the limitations of writing in file is depends on the Available Free Memory.

for deleting a file simply use delete method as below,

```
File fos = new File(FILENAME);
fos.delete();
```

Comment: Ok thanks, could it be a problem when doing textview.getText().toString(); ?? I don't know what's causing it..

Comment: it should no give any problem, if you are getting error/exception the please post your logcat for better understanding

Comment: Ok, i'll do that in a sec, but are you sure FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.delete();
 is correct, i tried it and i'm getting an error under fos.delete();

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure, and such operation you should use in try catch block. also tell me which error you are getting

Comment: It says i need to add a cast, even when i do, it still says i need to add a cast. also, there is no function called .delete for the fos object..

Comment: sorry that delete method is of File Class. For the cast problem , kindly upload your code

Comment: Yeah, this is what i'm trying but i don't know the directory, plus, it's the toast is returning false:

Comment: String tag = v.getTag().toString();
                  File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+tag);
                  String s = new Boolean (file.isFile()).toString();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, 1500).show();
                  file.delete();

Comment: put a S.O.P after File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+tag); this line and see, that, is that line really get executed ?

Answer (score 0):

You want `Context.deleteFile(String filename)` to delete the file. There shouldn't be any reason why the file is limited. Check your writing and reading code.